# NDK Automatic build in eclipse OSX Invoking autoreconf in build directory:

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

this time with a droid related question.

Im running Eclipse Helios and Mac OS X 10.6.8

I have been following a book and a few tutorials on building the NDK from both command line and Eclipse.

I am copying the source over there is no static library business.  I can compile from the command line fine with the "ndk-build" executable and it works fine.

Though i need to compile inside Eclipse for the reasons i don't need to go into here.

Ive tried 2 techniques and the one i have seen working is to convert my Project to a c++ project and then in Project / Properties / c/c++ Build tab / Build Command i set to ndk-build , this is set to be visible in my path (hence why it compiles when i go to directory and use ndk-build from Terminal)

I then in the C/C++ General tab add the following locations as include directories :

```
/Users/Me/Code/Android/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/include

/Users/me/Code/Android/android-ndk-r7b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include

/Users/me/Code/Android/android-ndk-r7b/sources/android/native_app_glue
```

Then when i go to compile i don't get any out put i just get the following error:

```
Invoking autoreconf in build directory: /Users/me/Code/Android/DroidBlaster

sh -c autoreconf -i 
autoreconf: `configure.ac' or `configure.in' is required

Configuration failed with error
```

Ive tried a few other tutorials but to no avail, if i could award a bounty on this is would as its urgent i get this fixed.

Cheers community :)

NOTE:

Ive worked out that it is using auto tools to build the project where this is incorrect as i should be building with the NDK , getting closer to an answer hopefully. Seems that i cant convert my Android project with CDT to a custom build configuration, might be a bug to do with Eclipse, trying a fresh install

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i worked it out, it was because i was trying to compile using Auto tools when i should have set up the project when i should have been using "Convert to C/C++ project" didn't help though that eclipse installed CDT incorrectly and i had to reinstall to get the right plugins.